# Application gettext not visible for Django translation on Mountain Lion

Tags: django, translation, homebrew, gettext, xgettext

I'm trying to translate my applications in my Django project. My development machine works under control OSX Mountain Lion, which out of the box doesn't have installed gettext, so I've installed this application with Homebrew:

```
brew install gettext
```

This command installed gettext-0.18.3.1.

After that I try to generate messages to my applications:

```
python manage.py makemessages -l pl
```

in result I get message:

```
CommandError: Error running xgettext. Note that Django internationalization requires GNU gettext 0.15 or newer.
```

Do you have any advice how to launch translation process on Mountain Lion with gettext installed via Homebrew?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

gettext is probably not on the PATH. This should work:

```
brew install gettext
brew link gettext --force
```

Comment: Ludwik, thanks a lot. Linking was a missed step in my environment. Now everything works properly.

Comment: Sudo would not work for me. Instead, I and apparently some others on SO have needed to add the flag --force to the brew link command for it to have the expected effect.

Comment: Don't use sudo! Use --force.

Answer (score 2):

What Ludwik Trammer comment `brew` commands does is automatically linking the contents of `/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/{VERSION}/bin/` into `/usr/local/bin/`.

If somebody arrives here and the `sudo brew link gettext` command is not working or returning warnings to him/her (because running `brew` with sudo is not usually a good option) it is possible to do the same manually, with no root privileges, like this:

```
DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/{VERSION}/bin/
for n in `ls $DIR`; do ln -s $DIR$n /usr/local/bin/$n; done
```

Then you have all the `gettext` related commands properly linked in your local `bin` directory.